# Populating select options from Beans in struts

Tags: java, struts, struts-1

I am Having Struts 1.2 bean as below which contains Locations in Array

**Register.java**

```
public class Register extends ActionForm 
{   
  private String[] userLocation = {"Chennai", "Bangalore", "Delhi", "Singapore"};
  .
  .
  //Getters and Setters
  .
  .
  .

}
```

I want to populate this in Dropdown select in options.I tried the Following code but it ain't working.Any Idea how to do this.Is it possible to do this with out using collection by using array.

**RegisterForm.jsp**

```
<html:select property="userSelectedLocation">
    <html:options  property="id" labelProperty="name" />
 </html:select>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read the documentation of the [select](http://struts.apache.org/release/1.2.x/userGuide/struts-html.html#select) tag and of the [options](http://struts.apache.org/release/1.2.x/userGuide/struts-html.html#options) tag.

The select tag expects to find the selected value of the select box in a property. You gave it `userSelectedLocation` as the property, but the action form doesn't seem to have any `getUserSelectedLocation()` method.

The options tag gets options from a collection of values. The place where it gets the collection depends on three attributes: collection, name and property. The documentation says:

> Only property is specified - The value of this attribute is the name of a property of the ActionForm bean associated with our form, which will return the collection.

This means that the options tag looks for a method `getId()` in the action form that would return the array of values. It doesn't seem you have such a method.

The documentation clearly explains how the tag works. If you told us what you want to do (what do you want the select options to have as value and as labels, what is the property that contains the selected value), we could tell you what to use.

Comment: Thank you so much for Reply I am new to Struts My Only doubt is whether I can populate values from array because I already learnt how to populate from collection.Since there is a way for populating values from array for Checkbox I want to let myself get clear whether same thing is possible for dropdown.thank you so much

Comment: Try it, and see. IIRC, STruts supports arrays just fine. But using arrays is generally not a good idea anyway. Why don't you use a `List<String>` instead?